# Notation for sampling specific number of samples from distribution

Tags: probability, notation, scientific-notation

I am in the process of writing a scientific paper. At a certain point I want to mention a sampling operation, namely that a variable hereafter called X is a sample obtained from a distribution T. Normally I would show this as `X ~ p(T)`. However in my case it is very important to explicitly mention the size of that sample in order to highlight the fact that I am obtaining exactly `k` samples from that distribution. I thought of incorporating that in the distribution and write `X ~ p(T; k)` but this feels wrong: the distribution is the same regardless of how many samples I drew from it. I could also write `X ~ p(T) so that |X| = k` or perhaps `X = {x_i ~ p(T) for i in [0, k)}` but I was hoping for a more succinct notation if one exists.

Answer (score 4):

This would be a fairly standard way to represent a random sample from $T$: $\mathbf X_k=\{X_1,\dots,X_k\}$ with $X_j\overset{\text{i.i.d.}}{\sim} T$.

None of the other notations you suggested are in common usage and will almost indefinitely confuse a reader unless explicitly defined.

Another slightly more compact option would be:
$\mathbf X_k=\{X_j\}_{j=1}^k$ with $X_j\overset{\text{i.i.d.}}{\sim} T$.